# Component CustomerListComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm experimenting with **Angular Lazy Load**, I have a strange error, while one of the route work flawlessly, while the other (similar structure and implementation) give me an error.
Here is my simple code:

in `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: 'app/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: 'app/orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

while in `orders.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { OrdersRoutingModule } from './orders-routing.module';
import { OrderListComponent } from './order-list/order-list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OrdersRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [OrderListComponent]
})
export class OrdersModule { }
```

and in `orders-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OrderListComponent } from './order-list/order-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OrderListComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OrdersRoutingModule { }
```

when i go to `localhost:4200/orders` **everything works flawlessly**, i.e. no error, and **the lazy loading feature** works as expected.

while in `customers.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CustomersRoutingModule } from './customers-routing.module';
import { CustomerListComponent } from './customer-list/customer-list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CustomersRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [CustomerListComponent]
})
export class CustomersModule { }
```

and in `customers-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomerListComponent } from './customer-list/customer-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CustomerListComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CustomersRoutingModule { }
```

**But** when i go to `localhost:4200/customers` it will give me **an error**:

`Error: Component CustomerListComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

Why is this happening only on `customers` route? How to fix this?

Comment: as it turns out i just need to stop `ng serve` and restarting it again. weird.

Comment: This is normal. You need to restart with ng serve whenever you add a new module